# MongoDB : Update only those objects in a collection whose 'Id' exists in a list

Tags: node.js, mongodb, linq, mongoose, c#-4.0

I have a MongoDb collection that I need to update.
The collection's JSON object consists of a few elements, 'Id' being one of them.
Now, I need to update only those objects in this collection whose 'Id' matches the ones I have in temporary list, 'TempList'.

I tried doing something like this, (see below and notice the 'filter' parameter) but it throws me an error,

```
await MyAccounts.UpdateManyAsync(w => TempList.Any(y => y.Id == w.Id),
        Builder.Update
        .Set(w => w.Elem1, blah1)
        .Set(w => w.Elem2, blah2) 
        .AddToSet("Elem3", blah3));
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: what is the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make `tempList` a list of IDs for the following to work and not a list of objects.

```cs
            var filter = Builders<MyAccount>.Filter
                            .Where(a => tempList.Contains(a.Id));

            var update = Builders<MyAccount>.Update
                            .Set(a => a.Elem1, "blah1")
                            .Set(a => a.Elem2, "blah2")
                            .AddToSet("Elem3", "blah3");

            collection.UpdateMany(filter, update);
```

here's a test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Account : Entity
    {
        public string Elem1 { get; set; }
        public string Elem2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            (new[]
            {
                new Account{
                 Elem1 = "first-elem1",
                 Elem2 = "first-elem2"
                },
                new Account{
                 Elem1 = "second-elem1",
                 Elem2 = "second-elem2"
                },
                new Account{
                 Elem1 = "third-elem1",
                 Elem2 = "third-elem2"
                }
            }).Save();

            var tempList = DB.Queryable<Account>()
                             .Select(a => a.ID)
                             .Take(2)
                             .ToList();

            DB.Update<Account>()
              .Match(a => tempList.Contains(a.ID))
              .Modify(a => a.Elem1, "blah1")
              .Modify(a => a.Elem2, "blah2")
              .Modify(a => a.AddToSet("Elem3", "blah3"))
              .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! That was what I was looking for.